# How to tap on an element multiple times in a faster way through selenium, appium, java and android

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

I want to automate a scenario using selenium, java, appium and android for tapping on an element multiple times in a faster way then a button appears, I have tried through java code using for loop with selenium webdriver click/appium touchactions tap but nothing helped me.

Comment: Can you share when you used above approaches what is the issues coming ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform multiple tap on the element.

**Use the below code:**

```
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.id("someID"));

TouchAction actionOne = new TouchAction();
actionOne.tap(element);
actionOne.release();

TouchAction actionTwo = new TouchAction();
actionTwo.tap(element);
actionTwo.release();

MultiTouchAction action = new MultiTouchAction();
action.add(actionOne);
action.add(actionTwo);
action.perform();
```

Add as many taps as possible if you need more than two. This should work.

Comment: `TouchAction` is deprecated.